# Reshaping a broadcasted expression

Tags: arrays, julia

I would like to make the following broadcasted expression work:

```
J = rand(4,4)
fx1 = rand(2,2)
fx2 = rand(2,2)
@. J[:,1] = fx1 + fx2
```

I really want some kind of:

```
@. J[:,1] = vec(fx1 + fx2)
```

where this `vec` is saying it should reshape to be 4x1, but I don't want to have to make this allocating. How could this be generically handled (i.e. no indexing on the fx)?

Comment: How about `@. J[:,1] = vec(fx1) + vec(fx2)`? This could in principle allocate two temporaries, but I assume that's easy enough for the compiler to elide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility, is instead of `vec`-ing the `fx1` and `fx2` to reshape the slice of `J`:

```
Jcol = reshape(view(J,:,1),(2,2))
@. Jcol = fx1 + fx2
```

Not sure about efficiency, but it may give a clearer perspective depending on the surrounding algorithm. The LLVM code seems short enough and the assignment statement is clear.

Comment: Using BenchmarkTools `@btime @. Jcol = fx1 + fx2` gives 0 allocations.

Comment: Good point.  You can just use `reshape` here — it should always return a "view".  In fact, as a final permutation, I think you could also express this as `@. J[reshape(1:4, 2, 2), 1)] = fx1 + fx2`.  Theoretically it could be the same performance, but we don't have all the optimizations in place for using reshaped ranges as indices yet so it'll be slower for now.

Comment: Updated with simpler `reshape`

Answer (score 3):

You can "exempt" `vec` from the `@.` macro by protecting it with a `$`:

```
julia> expand(:(@. J[:,1] = $vec(fx1) + $vec(fx2)))
:((Base.broadcast!)(+, (Base.dotview)(J, :, 1), (vec)(fx1), (vec)(fx2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since vecs are views, the following works:

```
J = rand(4,4)
fx1 = rand(2,2)
fx2 = rand(2,2)
vfx1,vfx2 = vec(fx1),vec(fx2)
@. J[:,1] = vfx1 + vfx2
```

I don't think there's a way to do it in one line like I wanted, but this is fine.